# Logging does not work on the server, but on the local machine the code works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I run it on the local machine, collects the data and writes them to the log, but this does not happen on the server.

```
from bravo import Bravo
from ozon import OzonAPI
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import django
import os
import sys

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def create_log():
    t = datetime.now()
    log_directory = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'logs', str(t.year), str(t.month), str(t.day))
    logfile = os.path.join(log_directory, '{}-{}-{}.log'.format(t.hour, t.minute, t.second))

    try:
        os.makedirs(log_directory, exist_ok=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to create log directory: {}'.format(e))

    log = logging.getLogger("my_log")
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    FH = logging.FileHandler(logfile, encoding='utf-8')
    basic_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : [%(levelname)s] : %(message)s')
    FH.setFormatter(basic_formatter)
    log.addHandler(FH)
    log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))  # Add stream handler for console output
    log.info('Start program')
    return log, t

def main():
    log, _ = create_log()

    setting = Settings.objects.all()[0]
    if not setting.mode:
        log.info('Program mode is disabled')
        return

    t1 = datetime.utcnow()
    bravo = Bravo()
    ozon = OzonAPI("I deleted here API")

    log.info('Fetching product list from Ozon...')
    products = ozon.get_product_list()
    warehouse_id = ozon.get_warehouses()[0]['warehouse_id']

    products_for_upload = []
    for product in products:
        if product['offer_id'].startswith('BR-'):
            try:
                stock = bravo.get_product_stock(product['offer_id'][3:-2])
                log.info("{} - {}".format(product['offer_id'], stock))
                products_for_upload.append(
                    {
                        'offer_id': product['offer_id'],
                        'product_id': product['product_id'],
                        'stock': stock,
                        'warehouse_id': warehouse_id,
                    }
                )
            except Exception as e:
                log.error("{} - {}".format(product['offer_id'][3:], e))

    log.info('Updating stocks on Ozon...')
    update_result = ozon.update_stocks(products_for_upload)
    log.info(update_result)

    t2 = datetime.utcnow()
    diff = t2 - t1
    log.info('Program execution time: {} seconds'.format(diff.total_seconds()))

    return update_result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bravoparser.settings")
    django.setup()
    from main.models import Settings

    log = logging.getLogger("my_log")
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    FH = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'logs', 'main.log'), encoding='utf-8')
    basic_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : [%(levelname)s] : %(message)s')
    FH.setFormatter(basic_formatter)
    log.addHandler(FH)
    log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))  # Add stream handler for console output
    log.info('Start program')

    result = main()
    log.info('Program result: {}'.format(result))
```

It does not write data to the server, but on the local machine everything goes smoothly, tell me what could be the reason

This is a piece of file with logging:

```
2023-06-06 20:51:58,298 : [INFO] : Fetching product list from Ozon...
2023-06-06 20:52:02,911 : [INFO] : BR-195090-I - 0
2023-06-06 20:52:03,596 : [INFO] : BR-183024-I - 0
2023-06-06 20:52:04,283 : [INFO] : BR-183440-I - 0
2023-06-06 20:52:04,968 : [INFO] : BR-183441-I - 0
2023-06-06 20:52:05,671 : [INFO] : BR-183393-I - 0
2023-06-06 20:52:06,220 : [INFO] : BR-195092-I - 0
2023-06-06 20:52:06,905 : [INFO] : BR-195094-I - 0
2023-06-06 20:52:07,607 : [INFO] : BR-195093-I - 0
2023-06-06 20:52:08,309 : [INFO] : BR-195091-I - 0
2023-06-06 20:52:09,074 : [INFO] : BR-183394-I - 0
```

I've tried everything I can, please help me figure out what's wrong with my code

`

Comment: This doesn't look like the manage.py generated by django, and you've brought in a lot of dependencies without a requirements file. If you're configuring the logger directly, maybe drop all the bravo ozon and django stuff from the reproduction here?

Comment: I do not know how to do it

Comment: I'm just guessing, but on the server maybe it's running a django app with the logging config from settings.LOGGING, so it's never executing this code to set up this logger.

Comment: @KennyOstrom
How it's fix?